# Shorten NFS share paths via symbolic links

Tags: linux, networking, nfs, shared-folders

I have a large number of NFS shares on a private server of mine, and they all exists fairly deep in the directory tree, ie:

```
Share list:
/data/files/external/share_a
/data/files/external/share_b
/data/files/external/share_c
```

I have to access these shares periodically, and always via command-line, ie:

```
mount -t nfs 192.168.1.5:/data/files/external/share_a /mnt/network/share_a
```

Is there a way to shorten the paths as far as the NFS client sees them. I'm thinking of making a directory on the server called "shares", which contains symlinks to the roots of the folders, then sharing the symlinks instead of the folders.

eg:

```
Share List:
/shares/share_a
/shares/share_b
/shares/share_c

Symlink details:
/shares/share_a ==> /data/files/external/share_a
/shares/share_b ==> /data/files/external/share_b
/shares/share_c ==> /data/files/external/share_c
```

Will this sort of thing work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server, use

```
mount --bind
```

to "link" in what you want.